# vim regex the pipe is not escaped in a execute command

Tags: regex, vim

i was trying to create an operator pending mapping for markdown headers, an exercise in learning vim script the hard way here is the line from my vimrc:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown :onoremap ih :<c-u>execute "normal! ?\\(^==\\+$\\|^--\\+$\\)\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
```

i have this error

```
E486: Pattern not found: \(^==\+$|^--\+$\)
```

i tried some modifications but i have the same result, it's like the pipe is never escaped !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a `:map` command, use `<Bar>` instead of the pipe symbol:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown :onoremap ih :<c-u>execute "normal! ?\\(^==\\+$\\<bar>^--\\+$\\)\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
```

That long `:normal` command (that actually executes a search, an Ex command, and then some more commands, separated by `\r`) is ugly. You'd better use `:call search(...)` instead of the `?` command, and factor out the multiple commands into a `:function`.